# VirtualBox: Simultaneous Windows and Linux guests on Windows 10 host

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v

I am running VirtualBox on Windows 10.

I have disabled Hyper-V from previously using Hyper-V, where I didn't have much success running a Linux guest (and also struggled with the networking).

My Linux guests run fine, both using KVM paravirtualization.

I noticed, when starting the install of my Windows 10 guest, that the default paravirtualization option chosen by VirtualBox is Hyper-V (which is apparently the default for Windows guests).

So, my first question: Why does VirtualBox choose this when Hyper-V is not installed/enabled?

I am currently busy installing Windows 10 after having restarted and forced KVM as the paravirtualization interface, but notice that the installation is running quite slowly, though it seemed to be running as slowly when Default/Hyper-V was selected.

Is there a way to successfully run Windows and Linux guests on VirtualBox on a Windows host at decent speeds?

Comment: The paravirtualization interface is used on guest side only, therefore it doesn't matter if you have Hyper-V enabled on the host or not.

Comment: Running multiple VMs at "decent speeds" will really depend on your hardware specs. Use the recommended paravirtualization, it's what's the default (and generally best performing) for the guest OS to interface.  Using a KVM interface with Windows will likely reduce performance of the VM and likely require the VM Tools since I don't believe Windows ships with KVM hypervisor hooks.  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#gimproviders